# ArcGIS Android - ArcGISFeatureLayer error: EsriServiceException: Internal Server Error

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-android

I am developping an Android application using tse ArcGIS SDK for Android. I am facing a problem when querying a featurelayer: the featurelayer I am using is hosted in our ArcGIS Online, and this is code I am using for the query: 

`public final String mNonValidatedURL="http://LINK-TO-SERVICE/FeatureServer/0";
QueryParameters qParam = new QueryParameters();
            qParam.setReturnGeometry(true);
            qParam.setOutSpatialReference(wm);
            qParam.setWhere("Validation='Non-validé'");
            qParam.setReturnGeometry(true);
            qParam.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});
            Map<String, Order> obf = new HashMap<String, Order>();
            obf.put("Date", Order.ASC);
            qParam.setOrderByFields(obf);
            QueryTask qTask = new QueryTask(mNonValidatedURL);
try
            {
                FeatureResult results = qTask.execute(qParam);
                return results;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("freaking exception", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }`

sometimes the query is executed without problems but most of the time I am catching this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your code. Here is the worked code piece.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    QueryTask qTask;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


       qTask = new QueryTask("http://services3.arcgis.com/hjUMsSJ87zgoicvl/ArcGIS/rest/services/PINV/FeatureServer/0");

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncQueryTask ayncQuery = new AsyncQueryTask();
                ayncQuery.execute("test");
            }
        });

    }


    private class AsyncQueryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FeatureResult> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected FeatureResult doInBackground(String... params) {


            QueryParameters qParameters = new QueryParameters();
            String whereClause = "Validation='Non-validé'";
            String outFields[] = {"*"};
            qParameters.setReturnGeometry(true);
            qParameters.setOutFields(outFields);
            qParameters.setWhere(whereClause);



            try {
                FeatureResult results = qTask.execute(qParameters);
                return results;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FeatureResult results) {
            Envelope extent = new Envelope();

            if (results != null) {
                int size = (int) results.featureCount();
                for (Object element : results) {
                    if (element instanceof Feature) {
                        Feature feature = (Feature) element;
                        // turn feature into mGraphicQuery

                        if(feature.getGeometry().getType().equals(Geometry.Type.POLYGON)) {
                            SimpleFillSymbol sms = new SimpleFillSymbol(Color.GREEN, SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID);
                            SimpleLineSymbol sms2 = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.GREEN, 1f, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.SOLID);
                            sms.setOutline(sms2);
                            sms.setAlpha(100);

                            Graphic graphic = new Graphic(feature.getGeometry(),
                                    sms, feature.getAttributes());

                            Polygon p = (Polygon) graphic.getGeometry();
                            p.queryEnvelope(extent);
                            extent.merge(extent);


                        }

                        else if (feature.getGeometry().getType().equals(Geometry.Type.POINT)){

                            SimpleMarkerSymbol sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED,15,SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);

                            Graphic graphic = new Graphic(feature.getGeometry(),
                                    sms, feature.getAttributes());

                            Point p = (Point) graphic.getGeometry();
                            p.queryEnvelope(extent);
                            extent.merge(extent);
                        }







                    }
                }



            }
            if(results.featureCount()==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



        }

    }


}
```

Comment: First thank you for your Answer, my code looks exactly like this, I am using AsyncTask the same way you mentionned, and it's working but sometimes it shows an "internal server error" as I mentionned in the question and I don't know why. I don't even understand what this error means so I can't look for a workaround..

Comment: It causes by Esri's arcgis services maybe. You can debug your app or monitoring this error using Exception.

Comment: unfortunately debugging the application using LogCat doesnt show any further information about the error, like I posted in the picture in the question